# Psql Cannot call procedure from bash

Tags: postgresql, bash, stored-procedures, psql

I have a postgres procedure of a definition :

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc(IN VARCHAR(1), IN INT, IN INT, INOUT INT)`

When I'm tying to call it using bash variables I'm getting an error saying there's
no procedure namde `my_proc(**unknown**,int,int,int)` even with type casts I get the
same message but with `unknown` replaced with `character varying`

**Update**
the script I'm using is pretty basic

```
echo "P_LOG= " $P_LOG
echo "arg1= " $1
echo "arg2= " $2

psql -d magadb -U exploit -q <<<EOF
\set QUIET on
set datestyle='SQL, DMY'
\set LC_TIME='French'
CALL my_proc('P',0,0,0)
```

any help is uch appreciated

Comment: Chances of getting an answer are slim to none without the content of the Bash code you are using to call the procedure. Add that as update to your question.

Comment: thank you for the advice, hope I find an answer soon

Comment: You are either connected to the wrong database, or you forgot to qualify `my_proc` with the schema name.

Comment: The error message says 'proc', not 'my_proc'?

Comment: Post the procedure you are calling. At least  the 'header' definition.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a 2500 lines of code, and I think the header is already in the question's post, unless you want some other specific detail please feel free to give me details